# Insufficient permissions to save options

Tags: options

Hi I have built a settings page which from the menu leads to:
http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=theme_options

The problem is that when I go to save the options and I am an EDITOR user I get this error:
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

I am using User Role Editor plugin and edit_theme_options capability is enabled for the Editor user type.

What can I do to fix this? thanks

Comment: manage_options capability is also enabled for the Editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is the issue here, but if I remember right the current limitation of Settings API is that `manage_options` capability is required for everything to be saved properly.

Quick search shows it might get fixed in 3.2, see [this trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14365).

Comment: Yep; known issue. And thanks for pointing out that fix, Rarst!

Comment: I did enable that as well but to no avail.

Comment: You'll need to post actual code. I can confirm that the fix in the ticket works. (Also, it requires that you're running WordPress 3.2 RC.)

Comment: I am using WP v3.1.2 is there any way to get this working on that version? I have a theme options page in another site with v3.1 and the editor can save the options just fine :S